# How to load a merged JS file containing several modules with requireJs?

Tags: javascript, merge, requirejs

That's something I've struggled with for more than a year now, I don't get how we are supposed to load a JS file that contains several AMD modules at once to avoid making as many HTTP requests as there are JS files.

Since we have to define each module separately in the RequireJS config, how is it possible to load only one merged JS file containing all modules at once?

Here is my RequireJS loader: https://gist.github.com/Vadorequest/9553eaf27ac1f469cf63

In that file, what I'd like to merge are:

- The requirejs libs (domReady, text, markdown)
- The shared source code between the server and the client (Lang, MessageLang... View)

Because these files will increase progressively and increase the number of HTTP calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do this in a build step. Have you consider using [RequireJS Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#setup)?

The documentation is pretty solid and you will need to add a couple of parameters to your require config:

```js
{
  baseUrl: ".",
  paths: {
    jquery: "some/other/jquery"
  },
  name: "main",
  out: "scripts.js"
}
```

This will generate one file (scripts.js) with all your files in it. There is also a bundle option if you like to group some files together [requirejs bundles](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config)

I personally use gulp to take care of my build process so I actually use [gulp-requirejs-bundler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-requirejs-bundler) but the same principles apply.

Comment: I took a look at that optimizer a long time ago, but I didn't understand at the time that I **had** to use `r.js`, it's much clear now, thanks. I usually use grunt so https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs would do it for me, thanks!